# Jenkins initial setup not pregressing

Tags: jenkins, installation, rhel8

## I want to install jenkins on rhel8 in one of the azure vm.

When using systemctl start jenkins .
It fails and log says need to do initial setup with password provided in log file.
When I use port forwarding in my local machine and tried to access jenkins.
But the jenkins not loading page where i can input password

Tried to run jenkins without password and tried to add admin account